# Jquery validation spring mvc

Tags: spring, validation, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a "Create an account" form that is handled by spring. I am using jquery to auto-update some of the fields.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(

             function() {

                 $("#item1").keyup(function() {
                     var text= (this).value;
                     //modify text
                     $("#item4").val(text);

                    });


             });
    </script>

     <form:form action="${form_url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="object" enctype="${enctype}">
     <label for="Item1">Item1:</label>
     <input type="text" id="item1" name="item_1"/>
     <br></br>
     <br></br>
     <label for="Item2">Item2:</label>
     <input type="text" id="item2" name="item_2"/>
     <br></br>
     <br></br>
     <label for="Item3">Item3:</label>
     <input type="text" id="item3" name="item_3"/>
     <br></br>
     <br></br>
     <label for="Item4">Item4:</label>
     <input type="text" id="item4" name="item_4"/>
    </form:create>

<input id="proceed" type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Upon pressing the submit button I need to make sure the first field "item1" is not empty. I haven't found a solution to this uses spring forms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using the [jQuery-validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement such validation. It is recommended you do both client and server side.

For client side you can simple create a click listener to the submit button

```
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('#item1').val().trim() != '') $('.myform').submit()
  else { $('.item1_error').show();
}
```

Or (even better) use 3rd party validation library

For the server side you can use hibernate-validator and add `@NotEmpty` annotation to your form bean

```
public class MyForm {

  @NotEmpty private String item1;

  // ...

}
```

Then on your controller handler method just decorate the parameter with `@Valid`. Any errors can be checked through the BindingResult object

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String myhandler(@Valid @ModelAttribute("object") MyForm myForm, BindingResult binding) {
  if(binding.hasErrors()) {
    // ...
  }
}
```